# Climbing trees and getting equipment up there

Tags: equipment-recommendation, shooting-technique

I've been climbing a few relatively short trees, but I'm having trouble getting my DSLR up there without it swinging around and hitting branches. Is there a decent means to do this?

Comment: You could try to make the camera straps shorter.

Comment: Or a lot longer. Climb the tree with the strap in your hand and the camera on the ground. Then pull the camera up.

Comment: Try a backpack.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only for DSLR try put it inside your shirt hung by your neck.
Specially at autumn/winter with sweaters works for me.